# Any way to restore System Image backup in another partion?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-backup

I did backup of system in image from system backup and restore in windows 7. And I restored it but it replaced my old windows partition. I want to restore it to another partition. Anyway to do this? I mean restore to new partition where I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system image created using Windows 7 backup to restore to a different hard drive. These are the steps:

1. Boot into the repair disc / Windows installation disc
2. Select "Reimage your computer"
3. Connect the disk which contains the backups.
4. Choose the recommended system image or choose a different one if you wish.
5. On the next page select the time period of the image you want to restore to. Click Next.
6. Now choose "Format and repartition disks".
   Go ahead and complete the wizard.

Comment: I want to move Windows in different partition in same HDD. I tried using System Image backup but it restore in earlier partition not in where I want to restore. Now If I choose "Format and repartition disks" then all partition will be delete. Right?